# Session variable are not getting passed to other routes in flask

Tags: python, flask, session

The problem arised when I wanted to pass a session varibale to a route which is different from the one which the varibale is create in. I have imported all the libraries required and also I have provided the secret_key along with other varibale such as session_type and session_permenent.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
SECRET_KEY = "changeme"
SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
SESSION_PERMENENT = False
Session(app)

@app.route('/upload',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return request.files
        file = request.files['file'] 
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join('UPLOADED_FOLDER', filename))
        
        # Perform operation on the dataset file. Create a session variable named 'DF' for further use.
        if file.filename.split(".")[1] == 'csv':
            dataframe = pd.read_csv('UPLOADED_FOLDER/'+file.filename)
            session['filename'] = file.filename

@app.route('/processing',methods= ['POST', 'GET'])
def processing():
    return session.get('filename')

# result for this is {}
```

Comment: You have not set the app.secret_key value:
`app.secret_key = "changeme"`

You are simply setting a variable:  `SECRET_KEY = "changeme"` which is never accessed in the code that you have shown.

Answer (score -1):

You likely forgot to wrap your app with the Session instance

```py
from flask import Flask, session
from flask.ext.session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
Session(app)

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    session['key'] = 'value'
```

https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/